# How to Use the OnViewportPositionChange of TVertScrollBox

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am trying to figure out how to use the `OnViewportPositionChange` of TVertScrollBox for my visual component trigger when it reach to certain level. It appears to me that this event `OnViewportPositionChange` is useful for this purpose.

```
procedure TformMain.VertScrollBox1ViewportPositionChange(Sender: TObject;
  const OldViewportPosition, NewViewportPosition: TPointF;
  const ContentSizeChanged: Boolean);
begin
   ...
end;
```

How can I detect/determine if the `NewViewportPosition` meets the criteria (TPointF) to trigger if it is **True** a visual component to set as visible.

I will appreciate if someone could give a quick sample.

**ATTEMPT 1:** No response and I can't use the this operand type `>=`.

```
  if NewViewportPosition = PointF(VertScrollBox1.ViewportPosition.X, 720) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Success!');
  end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TPointF` has 2 properties you can use: `.X` and `.Y`. You can easily just examine the values individually for example:

```
if (NewViewPortPosition.X >= CurrPosition.X) or (NewViewPortPosition.Y >= CurrPosition.Y)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. I can now trigger from here. I have declared the variable `CurrPosition : TPointF` and assigned some heights of my visual components to be able to get the number. Again many thanks.